# How to call field of json in javafx/java

Tags: java

Currently I can call `jsonplaceholder/albums` API

using this code

```
 public class Main extends Application {

private static HttpURLConnection connection;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (status > 299){
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        } else {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        }
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            responseContent.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        System.out.println(responseContent);

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

and this is the output

[image]

I can easily call the `api`. But the problem is how can I map each fields from this array?

In my code, I'm using `responseContent` to get json data.

I tried `System.out.println(responseContent[2]);` just to print only the `title` but It keeps giving me red line.

[image]

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/getting-started.html

Comment: no screenshots please - instead copy/paste code and error messages. Also your problem is unrelated to fx ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responseContent` is of type `StringBuffer`, this is just a utility for building Strings, that is arrays of characters. What you require is a JSON parser to provide an API to access the JSON string, e.g. to access the 2nd element in the array.

There are many libraries available, including Jackson, Gson, JSON simple, JSON-b etc.